# If a mobile deposit is denied due to exceeding limit, can it be deposited in person still?

Tags: checking-account, deposits, limits

This might sound like a stupid question, but considering it just happened to me I bet it will help others sleep at night when they decide to do a mobile deposit after hours. Of course, that depends on the answer to the question.

My bank requires me to write:

```
My Signature
For Mobile Deposit Only
at Name Of My Bank
```

I attempted to make the deposit and received an error that the limit has been exceeded.

Has this happened to anyone? Help me and other future searches sleep (or not sleep) and tell me it won't be a problem even though it has already been endorsed in such a manner. It would be like pulling teeth to get the check re-issued just so I can deposit it in person.

**And the result after a good nights rest:**

Bank raised my limit and said there was no problem. Just so my post here is complete I inquired about taking it in person. They said they would contact client services and ensure there was not a pending deposit of the check, and if not... no issues depositing it regardless of it already being filled out on the back for mobile deposit only.

Sleep well.

Comment: #1 Google "(your bank) maximum mobile deposit".  #2 Drive to the bank and hope you can still deposit it even though it says "For Mobile Deposit Only".  #3 Change banks, because having to write "For Mobile Deposit Only" is absurd.

Comment: @RonJohn That was the first thing that I did. Unfortunately my bank doesn't feel like it's relevant to post that information. I can't find anything under terms of agreement, not in the app, not online... nowhere. Disappointing.

Comment: That stinks!  "Change banks" might should move higher on your priority list...

Comment: FWIW, The mobile deposit endorsement is part of the rules that govern how banks settle checks between themselves in the US. It's not something that particular bank made up. Most banks and CUs require it, and those that don't likely soon will, since due to recent regulations, it changes their risk in terms of being left on the hook for bad checks.

Comment: And all is well.

Comment: Also, it may be the case that they don't publish a mobile deposit limit because the limit is calculated dynamically depending on risk for a given deposit attempt (user's history, IP address, date and time, etc). Or it's calculated periodically based on account age and usage, or (as it sounds was the case here) bank staff can change it on a whim at a customer's request. Thus, listing a (single) limit on their website or in their terms would not be possible.

Comment: Glad you had a good outcome for your situation.

Comment: Me too. With mobile deposits becoming more and more popular, I bet a lot of people will land on this page eventually.

Comment: @RonJohn: The having to write "For Mobile Deposit Only" has been added to numerous bank agreements in the last year.

Comment: The mobile app for my banks says, in very small print, what mu current deposit limit is. It's not the same for each customer. My son's is (much) lower. This limit has been raised several times without intervention from me, I assume based on my balance and the fact none of my deposits has ever been returned. Also: recent check orders include a "For Mobile Deposit" checkbox on the back, so I don't have to write it all out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll be fine. Just take it to the bank. It’s happened to me and they gladly let me make the deposit in person and the endorsement is fine.